# Selenium 2 Webdriver and IE 9 Security Certificate

Tags: internet-explorer-9, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have some Selenium 2 Webdriver test cases for Firefox and Internet Explorer 9. When I access https URLs on IE9 (Windows 7 64bit) I get "There is a problem with this website's security certificate". At this point the test hangs and eventually fails. I tried:

Getting Selenium to click on the "Continue to this website (not recommended)." link. This can't be done as this error page is not your usual page. Same with JavaScript - it doesn't execute.

I tried adding the registry key
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_ERROR_PAGE_BYPASS_ZONE_CHECK_FOR_HTTPS_KB954312](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954312)
 that prevents the certificate-error-page from displaying - didn't work. Probably because I'm on Windows 7 with IE9.

Following [this](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.selenium.devel/4874) advice I tried using browsermob proxy, but there's very little documentation out there and I couldn't work it out.

Finally, I don't have admin access to my PC - e.g. no access to group policies. Selenium 2 Webdriver works fine on Firefox. I have all security zones enabled in IE Internet Options and if I run the tests on other URLs (http) then there is no problem.

Has anyone got a solution to this problem? Does anyone now hot to use browsermob proxy (or any other proxy) effectively to overcome this issue?

Thanks,
Damo

Comment: The Feature key you mentioned had nothing to do with HTTPS certificate acceptance. Your best bet is to install the certificate in the user's Trusted store (certmgr.msc) assuming that the error is that the root isn't trusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer on the SQA board:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1928/selenium-2-webdriver-and-ie-9-security-certificate

We created a certificate and it It worked like a charm.

Comment: I even had a certificate still the behaviour of IE was random ... but Nyegaard's Solution worked also ....

Answer (score 26):

Okay I just got it working under IE9 using C# and the following code:

```
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.Url(YOUR_URL);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

And now it will go to the intended page. For Java it's as simple as:

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.get(YOUR_URL);
driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");
```

Comment: Worked .... cool man ... the thing is this ... people copy ur code at all the places  :D

Comment: I actually used to simply perform a findElement(By.id("overridelink")) and it would work for IE11, but for some reason it cannot find the element for IE9. 
The element is named exactly the same, i can inspect it with IE Dev tool.

NO idea why selenium fails to find it through webdriver.findElement, but your javascript version seems to work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using the Selenium-Python bindings:

```
#region SSL workaround for IE
if "Certificate Error" in driver.title:
    driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();")
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in the past, give it a try,

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);      
Webdriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Tried it, but with no luck. Did you try this in IE9?

Comment: I haven't tried it on IE9. Does non-admin privileges allow you to install the security certificate in IE? or that's something you don't prefer?

Comment: The latest version does not include a override that accepts a DesiredCapabilities parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Any progess in this?
I'm trying to do this capabilities thing... but I don't know how to do it using Ruby :(

In chrome it is simple since you can use switches:

```
nav=Selenium::WebDriver.for(:chrome, :switches => %w[--ignore-certificate-errors -])
```

Maybe it is possible to do it for IE using switches

Answer (score 0):

there is a much simpler solution in case you use IE driver, documented in this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11577323/193974). The added benefit is that you don't have to be the site owner and you don't have to tangle with browsermob or the registry or any other low-level technology

Answer (score 0):

We can use the the following code.

```
wait =new WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10);

webdriver.get(url);
WebElement ele =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
               webdriver.findElement(By.linkText("Continue to this website (not  
               recommended)."))));
 ele.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have the correct idea, but fail in practice because the `WebDriver` doesn't navigate immediately to the certificate error page.  The correct implementation should wait a bit.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Certificate"));


driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```