# Selenium Python open on IE browser

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium with python. I am opening a internal link which give me a certificate error which need to click to proceed further.
 **"Continue to this website (not recommended)."**

I used various combinations in my code to overcome this but no help.

Please suggest what code I can modify in python to over come this.

```
    def test_login_aa(self):
    driver = self.driver
    driver.get("base_url")
    time.sleep(5)

    #driver.find_elements_by_id.to(('overridelink').click()");
    #driver.find_element_by_name("overridelink").click()
    #driver.find_element_by_name("overridelink").send_keys(ENTER);
    driver.find_element_by_name("overridelink").send_keys(ENTER);
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='overridelink']").click()
    #driver.find_elements_by_name("overridelink").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    #driver.findElement(By.name("overridelink")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);


    self.assertEqual("User Login", driver.title)
    driver.find_element_by_id("IDToken1").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("IDToken1").send_keys("username")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had luck using this method:

```
driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()")
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11577323/2626096

Comment: The above is implemented in Python. Try it out.