# Bypass "invalid security certificate" browser redirect when using selenium webdriver/python?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I have a written a series of Selenium webdriver tests in python, and am trying to execute them on Browserstack (love them so far).  The tests are on my company's test environment, which mimics our production environment except for the fact that it doesn't have a security certificate (we're an e-commerce site, no need to pay for one on our test environment).  Is there a way to bypass the browser redirect using selenium or Browserstack?  I can add selenium tests around it, but it will be very cumbersome as I have to do a seperate statement for each browser since they have differing behaviors.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got this answer from the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710619/selenium-2-webdriver-and-ie-9-security-certificate):

Give this a try:

```
    if "Certificate Error" in driver.title:
        driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()")
```