# Bypassing certificate error with Watir-WebDriver in Selenium Grid environment

Tags: ruby, ssl, internet-explorer-8, watir-webdriver, selenium-grid

I have setup a Grid Environment with 4 Windows ( IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11 ) VMs and an Ubuntu 12.04 VM with Chrome and Firefox.

Selenium Grid and Nodes are version 2.41.0 
as for ruby , i am using rvm, and using ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-linux]

I am driving the tests from a CentOs VM. Now when i try to run IE8 Tests, i see the remote windows machine bring up IE8, but first get a message in browser:

**"This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server."**

and later i get another page with cert warning.

**Certificate Error: Navigation Blocked
error:
The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.
Security certificate problems may indicate an attempt to fool you or intercept any data you send to the server**

I tried to do the registry hack making all 4 security levels in the IE8 equal , by
     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones
     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones

and equalize values for 0x2500 position in all zones.

But does not seem to work.
Any ideas here what a working solution is for ruby / watir-webdriver

Here is the base class

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -W0
require "rubygems"
require "test/unit"
require 'rspec'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
require 'mysql2'
require_relative 'lib/basic_ops'
require_relative 'data/data'
require_relative 'main_class'

include  GC
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.ie
caps.version = "8"
caps[:name] = "IE 8 on win7 , port 5560"

    BROWSER = Watir::Browser.new(
    :remote,
    :url => "http://selenium-hub-vm:4444/wd/hub",
    :desired_capabilities => caps)

URL = "https://target-vm/"
BROWSER.window.resize_to(950, 750)
BROWSER.window.move_to(0, 0)

main_class
```

so main_class.rb is where all the browser interactions are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did was to add the cert , that did not remove the cert error, so i used:

```
@browser.link(:id, "overridelink").click
```

right after

```
@browser.goto("https://<URL>/")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to get passed the Security Certificate issue.  I've never coded in Ruby before, so the syntax may be a bit off.

Python code:

```
driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()")
```

Ruby attempts:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('overridelink').click()")
driver.get "javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()"
driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

You may want this in an **if** statement too so as to check for the condition you need.

```
i.e.  if "Certificate Error" in driver.find_element_by_xpath("//title").text
```

There are similar solutions on the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710619/selenium-2-webdriver-and-ie-9-security-certificate) if none of my suggestions work.

Hope this is helpful or close to what you need.