# Skipping HTTPS certificates in internet explorer- for the tests run by Selenium

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I have to automate a test using Selenium, where selenium will:

1. Launch internet explorer
2. Login to a page (I use selenium we driver)
3. Perform few checks

Issue is, before I get step (2) login page, I have to provide https certificates as the connection uses https.
I don't have the server certificate.
Is there any way to skip this 'Add server certificate' page in IE?

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710619/selenium-2-webdriver-and-ie-9-security-certificate

Answer (score 0):

You could add your site to trusted sites on browser.

[Reference link here](https://superuser.com/questions/27268/how-do-i-disable-the-warning-chrome-gives-if-a-security-certificate-is-not-trust)

Or you could create a custom security certificate to pass https security for your site to deploy it on server location.

[Self signed certificate ssl](http://www.howtogeek.com/107415/it-how-to-create-a-self-signed-security-ssl-certificate-and-deploy-it-to-client-machines/)