# Bypass Security Certificate page on Microsoft Edge for Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to bypass the Security Certificate page for Microsoft Edge for Selenium Webdriver using Python.

[image]

I attempted solutions that worked for previous versions of Internet Explorer that I found at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710619/selenium-2-webdriver-and-ie-9-security-certificate), but none of them worked.

```
driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click();");
```

It seems like something close to the code above would probably work, but the Security Certificate page on Microsoft Edge is clearly different in some way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do to get past this Security Certificate screen.

- Locate the desired_capabilities class, which should be located
  somewhere in you Python folder.  It'll be in the file **desired_capabilities.py**.

> i.e.  C:\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common

- In **desired_capabilities.py**, Make sure the default desired capabilities object for the
  Microsoft Edge webdriver has **“javascriptEnabled”** set to **“True”**. 
  You may have to add the code for this.

[image]

- In the section of your code that encounters the Security Certificate page, verify you’re on the Security Certificate page and use javascript to select the continue option.

  ```
  if "Certificate error" in driver.title:
      driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('invalidcert_continue').click()")
  ```

The name of the object responsible for continuing passed the Security Certificate page is different for Microsoft Edge than it is for IE.  Hope this helps.